# Can't stack some values

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have three trees. The first two have some numbers stacked in them, and the last tree has the difference between the two first trees (first tree - second tree).

But the problem is when I open/close a blue part of the **THIRD THREE**, the numbers in it are sometimes replaced by an old number that I put at the very beginning of the creation of the tree.

On this function, I retrieve all of the numbers stacked in the trees in a double array (`nb_data` is my double array, `all_g` is the g tag who contains all of the number of each tree):

```
function retrieve_content_svgs(all_g, i) {
    var all_aftertext = all_g.selectAll(".node tspan.aftertext"); //On récupère tout les aftertext, rect qui contient des nombres.
    var nodelist_tmp = Object.values(all_aftertext)[0][0]; //Conversion d'object à nodelist
    nb_data[i] = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist_tmp); //Conversion Nodelist a array
    console.log(nb_data[2]);
}
```

Here is the JS Fiddle (my code was really too long to put here so I have only included the relevant part):

https://jsfiddle.net/p6ht42by/

Comment: What do you mean by "_sometimes_ replaced"? What conditions cause it to be replaced? How do we recreate your issue?

Comment: I have a total of three tree's, two are created automatically with the code, and the third is created by a duplication of the first, and this tree is created for the differance of the first and second tree, so i doesn't matter what tree i duplicate to create it because after this i will change his data before displaying it. But the problem is, when the tree is displayed for the first time, it work good, but when i click on a blue part of this third three, the value putted in on the first time (of the first tree) will be displayed instead of the changed value of the differance... :( @JamesWhite